# QNX 6.5 - Repack ifs root stage 2 for MIB2

Tags: qnx

I have been working on a custom patch for my car with MIB2 unit for some time and would like to try my modified MIBRoot file.
The command I used to repack everything is:

mkxfs -t ifs -nn -o ./ -r / ./mkifs_attributes.txt ./ifs_extracted ./patched_ifs.ifs

But the problem is that the repackaging is not working properly, because the mkifs_attribute.txt file used is probably not fine for my MIB2 or I have a version that is not correct.
In fact, when I do a:

diff -r ./original/ifs_extracted ./repack/ifs_extracted

all files in ./repack/ifs_extracted are different from the originals, when instead only the MIBRoot file should be different.

my mkifs_attribute contain this:

```
#Porsche PCM4/MIB2 ifs-root (stage 2) attributes file
#Before packing FS: EXPORT QNX_TARGET="/"
#Command to pack: mkxfs -t ifs -nn -o ./ -r / attributes.txt /unpacked_fs /packed_fs.ifs

[-followlink]        #Do not resolve links
[compress=2]         #LZO Compression
[-bigendian]         #Little Endian (ARMLE)
[-autolink]          #Do not auto link shared objects
[perms=777]          #chmod 777
[uid=0 gid=0]        #chown root:root

#You can add a script to be executed after mount here, one line only
#[+script] .script = {
#touch /dev/shmem/AudioFadedIn; touch /dev/shmem/production_mode}

#Symlinks. Add lines here to match your dumpifs symlinks
#[type=link] dest_file=source_file
[type=link] /lib/SPC_configuration.so=/lib/libSPC_configuration.so
[type=link] /lib/AudioConfig_ARM.so=/lib/libAudioConfig_ARM.so
[type=link] /lib/AudioConfig_DSP.so=/lib/libAudioConfig_DSP.so
[type=link] /usr/bin/flashunlock=/usr/bin/flashlock
[type=link] /usr/bin/libi2c-inic-master.so=/lib/libi2c-inic-master.so.1.0
[type=link] /lib/librdshbfpga.so.1.0.0=/lib/librdshbfpga.so
[type=link] /lib/libSysMoCCAFrameworkSharedSo.so=/lib/libSysMoCCAFrameworkSharedSo.so.6
[type=link] /lib/AudioConfig_DSP.so=/lib/libAudioConfig_DSP.so
[type=link] /lib/liba2itodspipc.so=/lib/liba2itodspipc.so.1
```

Or am i wrong something?
If anyone has a correct mkxfs and mkxfs_attribute.txt could you please provide it to me so I can give it a try?

Comment: I did the binary difference between a file from ./original/ifs_extracted/telnetdOriginal and the related file from ./repack/ifs_extracted/telnetdRepack and I noticed that they are quite different. Some bytes change both at the beginning and at the end: there are many zeros at the end of ./repack/ifs_extracted/telnetdRepacked file. I don't understand if it's the mkxfs not working or the compression algorithm.
This is a explanatory video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/127L7lDe3xAOS36rsQ-gyOydS4ok9Cf-5/view?usp=sharing